# Need to delete QValidator manually?

Tags: c++, qt, memory-leaks

Example code:

```
QDoubleValidator *validator = new QDoubleValidator();
myInputLineEdit->setValidator(validator);

// delete validator;
```

Note: myInputLineEdit is a QLineEdit pointer and will be deleted with its parent.

My question is, when should I delete validator, as it's manually created and setValidator() doesn't seem to take ownership of this pointer according to the documentation? If I don't delete it, will it be a memory leak?

I tried to delete it right after, like the commented code, and I noticed the validator of myInputLineEdit became 0 after that. So I think I may need to delete it after myInputLineEdit is deleted.

Another thought is, I could give validator a parent so it will be deleted along with its parrent, is this a good way to do that? What if there isn't a good candidator to be the parent?

Thanks

Comment: If you're interested in the reason why `setValidator` doesn't take ownership: it's probably because you can use the same validator for multiple input widgets, so it's a somewhat *shared* ownership. But QObjects don't have shared ownership but instead *unique* parent-ownership, so you need to set the parent to *some* widget (either the line edit or a parent of it, whatever makes most sense).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I tried to delete it right after, like the commented code, and I
>   noticed the validator of myInputLineEdit became 0 after that. So I
>   think I may need to delete it after myInputLineEdit is deleted.

It's because `QLineEdit` uses `QPointer` internally, which tracks `QValidator` object if it was deleted.

> and setValidator() doesn't seem to take ownership of this pointer
>   according to the documentation

`setValidator()` indeed does not set parent of QValidator.

> Another thought is, I could give validator a parent so it will be
>   deleted along with its parrent, is this a good way to do that? What if
>   there isn't a good candidator to be the parent?

You can either delete it manually, use smart pointers or do like @crayzeewulf said - set `myInputLineEdit` as parent (using `QValidator` constructor or `setParent()`). Parent takes care about deleting its children, so it is a way to go. Usually object to which validator is assigned is a good parent.

> If I don't delete it, will it be a memory leak?

If you neither set a parent nor delete it, there will be a memory leak.

Comment: Thanks guys. I didn't use myInputLineEdit as the parent because i want to use this validator for several QLineEdit objects, as mentioned by @leemes. So there will be a problem when one of them gets deleted. I guess I've two choices here: 1, creater one validator for each QLineEdit; 2, since all these QLineEdit objects are members of a common class, which is also a QObject class, i can use it as the parent.

Comment: @Leo Go with the option 2.

Answer (score 3):

Use `mInputLineEdit` as the `parent` of `validator` as in the example [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/widgets-lineedits.html). The destructor of a parent destroys all child objects (see [this](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#QObject)). This is the "qt way" of handling [ownership trees](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/objecttrees.html).